# Display plist data into UItableview?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have plist but i cant display data into tableview so please help me thanks in advance.

Comment: Provide us with the information what you have done so far to solve your problem. At which state are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a .plist file in your resources, you can easily load it using the following code:

```
NSDictionary *loadedDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: filePath];
```

or

```
NSArray *loadedArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile: filePath];
```

(the correct one will depend on the root item in your plist file rather it is dictionary or array)

after that, I believe, it will be easy enough to display this data in the table view